# How to close a window but not actually quit/exit the program

Tags: unity, macosx, minimize

I use Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity).
How would I do that when I pressed the close button to Minimize the window, as is the case with Mac OS. The program is closed but is still running in memory until it is completely closed by right-clicking and Quit.
This would be particularly useful especially for programs such as Thunderbird and various Twitter clients.
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Well i dint exactly get your question but as you have mentioned MAC OS,if you would want the feature of rolling up a window to a single bar,it can be done.

Comment: @Nirmik rolling window to a single bar is very much possible in ubuntu (also 12.04). I am using it (install ubuntu tweak). I think the author wants to do minimization on click on close.

Comment: I understand that you are talking about something that happens with `RHYTHMBOX` in Ubuntu...rite?? You close it but it keeps playing untill you stop it from sounds menu..

Comment: @Web-E Yes I use it too.I just asked it to confirm whether he wants any help with it.Do you know any way to do what he is asking??

Comment: @Nirmik Yes, exactly like Rhythmbox in Ubuntu =)

Answer (score 4):

A simple trick that I use when I want to have a program running, but out of sight, it is sending it to another workspace. I usually use two workspaces, one for the programs that I'm working on and another one for the "sleepers".

Comment: I am also used it, but this is not it, because I several times by accident press close button.